# Calling many functions in one HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html, pandorabots

The following code for a browser chat works as a whole, but it's not neat.

```
<p>chat in silence:</p>
<input id="yousay" name="input" size="52" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { doTalk(); }"/>

<p>chat in with music:</p>
 <textarea onfocus="clearContents(this);" id="chat" cols="50" rows="2" ></textarea>

 <button type="button" onclick="triggerAll();">answer</button>
```

these are the scripts:

```
<script src="scripts/soundEngine.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/animationEngine.js"></script> 
<script src="scripts/talk.js"></script>
```

this calls the bot API

```
<script>
  var pb = new Pandorabot("aiaas.pandorabots.com", 'validid', 'validname', 'validid'); 
  function doTalk() {
    var input = document.getElementById("yousay").value;
    document.getElementById("yousay").value = "";
    pb.talk(input, function(data) {
      var response = data["responses"];
      document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = response;
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
</script>
```

and this a function to call them all at once:

```
<script>
      function triggerAll(){
        doTalk();
        play_song();
        animate_song();
      }
</script>
```

Apparently, `<textarea>` calls `play_song()` and `animate_song()`, but does not call `doTalk()`

Is there a way I can put all function calls within one `tag` and reduce the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In html you can call function that calls all of them.
Like you have script one,two,three and you do this

```
<randomtag onclick="call_all()"></randomtag>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function call_all(){
    one();
    two();
    three();
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var pb = new Pandorabot("aiaas.pandorabots.com", 'validid', 'validname', 'validid');
```

arguments here are valid? If this arguments aren't valid then function `doTalk()` doesn't exist and you can't call them